# Hello, I get Error while updating data using Meteor aldeed:autoform.Any workarounds?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-autoform

This is the error i get

**update error: Error: Author is required**

Here is my Schema:

```js
ServiceSchema=new SimpleSchema({
    website:{
        type:String,
        label:"Website"

    },
    store:{
        type:String,
        label:"Store"
    },
    author:{
        type:String,
        label:"Author",
        autoValue:function(){
                       return this.userId
        }
      


    }
});
```

Here i call quickform with type update:

```
  {{>quickForm collection="Services" id="updateService" type="update" doc=this }}
```

The same schema works for insert but not for updating.I tried setting the author value as optional but it still doesn't work.Am i doing something wrong?